# Why can't I open BLEND files with Blender?

Tags: blend-files

I've been trying to open a rig I got last week, but it keeps trying to open it in Internet Explorer, and when I try to open it with Blender, it says there was a 'catastrophic failure'. Can anybody Explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Start blender, and try opening the file with  ***File*** > ***Open*** (or Ctrl+ O)

Comment: For one it sounds like you accidentally set the default opening program to IE for that extension whatever it is. Also could be a malformed file or something... can you share the rig or where you got it from?

Comment: like iKIsR wrote: this is about extension assign. Try click left on any .blend, select "open with" and choose Blender. Also tick "always use this software for open this type of file".  I write this from memory, (I'm not on windows, suppose than you are) so text can be different, but the way is important :-)

Comment: Note that this is not an issue with blender, but with how your system is configured.